# How does the zip code validation work?

Tags: magento-1, validation

There's a class called "validate-zip" and "validate-zip-international". How does that function know how many digits to validate against? Where do you adjust the settings that affect how many digits to validate against?

This is for Magento 1

Comment: You can see magento 2 validations at /lib/web/mage/validation.js from your magento root

Comment: Forgot to mention that this is for Magento 1

Comment: @angelo12 did my answer not answer your question?

Answer (score 5):

You can see all of the validation rules in `js/prototype/validation.js`

```
['validate-zip', 'Please enter a valid zip code. For example 90602 or 90602-1234.', function(v) {
     return Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v) || /(^\d{5}$)|(^\d{5}-\d{4}$)/.test(v);
}],
```

If we inspect the regex code: `/(^\d{5}$)|(^\d{5}-\d{4}$)/` 

It validates for these formats: `12345` or `12345-1234`